# MLflow: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unix_sock'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mlflow

I have deployed MLflow on Cloud Run (GCP).  I have provided the backend URI with the following format:
mysql+pymysql://:@/?unix_sock=/cloudsql/

When I am opening MLflow, I am getting the following error in the Cloud Run Logs:
mlflow.store.db.utils: SQLAlchemy engine could not be created. The following exception is caught.
**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unix_sock'.

Do MLflow support unix-connections while connecting to DB?

Following is the blog that I am following:
https://dlabs.ai/blog/a-step-by-step-guide-to-setting-up-mlflow-on-the-google-cloud-platform/

Github Repo:
https://github.com/dlabsai/mlflow-for-gcp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced `unix_sock` with `unix_socket` acc. to the pymysql documentation -
https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/connections.html